# making the text go under the other

Tags: html, css

I want the text "With Resistance Bands" to appear in the list view without seeing With "Resistan..... ".

How can I make that text fit inside without altering the size of the text any lower?

On web view it is fine of course but on mobile view it does not fit on.

I have tried `"& shy ;` but that did not work.

```
<li>
  <a href="item1.html" style="color:green;font-family:Quicksand;font-size:20px">
    <img src="" class="ui-li-has-thumb"/> 
                    With Resistance Bands
   </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably just need `white-space: normal;`

Comment: Top man! Thank you, that simple. It has not mentioned that to me on codeacademy yet ha

Comment: No problem! If it's a workable solution, please accept it as the answer :)